# Add more labels to colorbar legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making some plots in ggplot with a colorbar legend like below. By default the legend has only 4 labels showing the value of specific colors. There are theme elements which can change the size of the colorbar, but not the number of labels. How can I increase the number of labels?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=carb, color=disp)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2,'cm'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the `breaks` in `scale_color_continous()`

```
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=carb, color=disp)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2,'cm'))

g1 + scale_color_continuous(breaks=seq(50,500,25))
```

[image]